# Access on-prem resources via Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to access on-prem resources (file share on a file server) via Azure, but I'm stuck and don't know how to continue.

On Prem: 1 Domain Controller and 1 File Server (Server 2019 Std). Both are joined to a local domain. The DC runs Azure AD Connect for sync.
Client: Laptop running Windows 10, joined to the Azure AD. Is in a *different* network.

Goal: Laptop should access the file share. 
For sure I just could use a VPN or smth, but I'm trying to learn a bit Azure. 
I'm referring to the following Microsoft Website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/access-resources
*"You can also allow access to on-premises resources like line of business (LOB) apps, file shares, and printers. To allow access, use Azure AD Connect to synchronize your on-premises Active Directory with Azure Active Directory."*

Answer (score 0):

I dont think those are related at all. Network path must exist between your laptop and the file share. And the Azure AD Connect can help you with authentication\authorization, not with establishing the network connection. You should use VPN to establish network connectivity and you can use Azure AD Connect to sync identities to be able to use the same identity to access resources in the cloud\on-premises

Comment: I understand. I thought there is a way like Application Proxy to publish the file server to the cloud (my explanation is maybe bad, no native english speaker).